# eliminar un campo dinamicamente pero a partir de que se agregue otro campo

Tags: php, jquery, tabla-dinámica

quiero que me aparesca el boton de eliminar a partir del segundo campo porfavor ;v es mi jquery el cual clona el campo , las filas es cada una de mis tablas

```
    $(function(){

    $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
      $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila').appendTo("#tabla");
    });
    $("#adicional2").on('click', function(){
      $("#tabla2 tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila2').appendTo("#tabla2");
    });
    $("#adicional3").on('click', function(){
      $("#tabla3 tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila3').appendTo("#tabla3");
    });
    $("#adicional4").on('click', function(){ 
      $("#tabla4 tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila4').appendTo("#tabla4");
    });

    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
    });
  });  
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

parte de mi html

```
<div id="tab3">
   <center><h2 style="font-family:cursive;">Gastos Velada: </h2> </center>
  <table class=""  id="tabla4">

          <tr class="fila4">
      <td><select id="letra2" name="tipo_gasto" class="select" required="">
        <option>Gastos velada:</option>
        <option>Tansporte</option>
        <option>Alimentos</option>
         <option>Otros gastos</option>
      </select></td>


    <!-- <td><textarea required type="text" name="descripcion_gasto" placeholder="Ingrese descripcion"/></textarea><td>-->

      <td><input required id="letra2" type="number" class="redondeado" step="any" name="costo" placeholder="Ingrese Costo"/><td>

     <td class="eliminar"><input type=image src="<?=URL ?>public/img/delete.png" width="35" height="35"/></td>
          </tr>

  </table>

   <br>
     <div class="btn-der">   
     <center><button  type="button" id="adicional4" class="boton_3" ><img src="<? 
    =URL 
    ?>public/img/anadir.png" width="25" height="25"/> CAMPOS</button></center>
    </div>
```

Comment: Deberias incluir to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes esconder el boton en la primera fila y mostrarlo a la hora de clonar.  Algo asi:

```js
$("#adicional4").on('click', function(){ 
  $("#tabla4 tbody tr:eq(0)")
    .clone().removeClass('fila4').appendTo("#tabla4").find(".eliminar").show();
});

$(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div id="tab3">
   <center><h2 style="font-family:cursive;">Gastos Velada: </h2> </center>
  <table class=""  id="tabla4">

          <tr class="fila4">
      <td><select id="letra2" name="tipo_gasto" class="select" required="">
        <option>Gastos velada:</option>
        <option>Tansporte</option>
        <option>Alimentos</option>
         <option>Otros gastos</option>
      </select></td>


    <!-- <td><textarea required type="text" name="descripcion_gasto" placeholder="Ingrese descripcion"/></textarea><td>-->

      <td><input required id="letra2" type="number" class="redondeado" step="any" name="costo" placeholder="Ingrese Costo"/><td>

     <td style="display:none;" class="eliminar"><i class="fa fa-times" width="35" height="35"/></td>
          </tr>

  </table>

   <br>
     <div class="btn-der">   
     <center><button  type="button" id="adicional4" class="boton_3" ><i class="fa fa-plus" width="25" height="25"></i> CAMPOS</button></center>
    </div>
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS  bro ¡¡¡¡¡ si me sirvió